# Django Ninja Testing

Tags: python, django, django-ninja

I am trying to create a test for an API I wrote using Django-Ninja.

Here is my Model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
```

Here is my schema:

```
class CountryAddSchema(Schema):
    name: str
    code: str
    timezone: str
```

Here is the post endpoint:

```
router.post("/add",
             description="Add a Country",
             summary="Add a Country", tags=["Address"],
             response={201: DefaultSchema, 401: DefaultSchema, 422: DefaultSchema, 500: DefaultSchema},
            url_name="address_country_add")
def country_add(request, country: CountryAddSchema):
    try:
        if not request.auth.belongs_to.is_staff:
            return 401, {"detail": "None Staff cannot add Country"}

        the_country = Country.objects.create(**country.dict())
        the_country.save()
        return 201, {"detail": "New Country created"}
    except Exception as e:
        return 500, {"detail": str(e)}
```

Finally, here the test function:

```
def test_add_correct(self):
    """
    Add a country

    """
    data = {
        "name": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=32)),
        "code": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=32)),
        "timezone": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=32))
    }

    respond = self.client.post(reverse("api-1.0.0:address_country_add"), data, **self.AUTHORIZED_HEADER)
    self.assertEquals(respond.status_code, 201)
    self.assertDictEqual(json.loads(respond.content), {"detail": "New Country created"})

    the_country = Country.objects.last()
    self.assertDictEqual(
        data,
        {
            "name": the_country.name,
            "code": the_country.code,
            "timezone": the_country.timezone
        }
    )
```

Please notice I have `self.AUTHORIZED_HEADER` set in `setUp`.

And here the error:

```
FAIL: test_add_correct (address.tests_country.CountryTest)
Add a country
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SOME_PATH/tests_country.py", line 80, in test_add_correct
    self.assertEquals(respond.status_code, 201)
AssertionError: 400 != 201
```

I can add a country using swagger provided with django-ninja. I mean the endpoint works. But I can not test it using `djano.test.Client`.

Any Idea?

### Update:

Here the curl code generated by swagger:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/address/country/add' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-API-Key: API-KEY' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "string",
  "code": "string",
  "timezone": "string"
}'
```

Comment: please output details with `assert respond.status_code == 201, str(response.content)` to see the validation error

Answer (score 2):

I had `{"detail": "Cannot parse request body"}` as an error.

Turns out, Django-ninja expects your data to be passed as a json, but by default, the `content_type` is set to `multipart/form-data; boundary=BoUnDaRyStRiNg` for the test client. When you explicitely mention the content type should be json, it will work.

```
Client().post(url, {"your": "dict"}, content_type="application/json")
```

Note: Setting the content-type in the headers will not work as it will get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to JSON:

```
self.client.post(
   reverse("api-1.0.0:address_country_add"),
   json.dumps(data),
   content_type="application/json", 
   **self.AUTHORIZED_HEADER
)
```

Comment: I already did try that. I found the solution. I used `urllib.parse.urlencode`. I'll post it my answer asap.

Comment: Hey hey, could you please still post the answer? Facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

In your test function when you are sending the data using the Django test client, make sure to send it as JSON data since your endpoint expects JSON:

```
def test_add_correct(self):
    """
    Add  country
    """
    data = {
        "name": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=32)),
        "code": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=32)),
        "timezone": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=32))
    }

    # Convert data to JSON format
    data_json = json.dumps(data)

    # Send the request with JSON data
    respond = self.client.post(reverse("api-1.0.0:address_country_add"), data=data_json, content_type='application/json', **self.AUTHORIZED_HEADER)

    # Rest of your test code_____
```

**This should align with the expectation of your API endpoint and resolve the 400 status code issue.**